# My Desktop Performance issue

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, memory, cpu, performance

My desktop computer specification is

- Processor: AMD FX 8320
- Motherboard: Asus M5A97
- RAM: Kingston HyperX 16 GB (8*2)
- HD: 1TB WD Black
- Graphics Card: 2GB Saphire 5450
- SMPS: Cooler Master 650W
- OS: Windows 10

I optimized my desktop computer well.

- Limited applications are installed in my desktop computer.
- Limited applications are enabled in startup.
- In msconfig, limited services are enabled.
- Browsers are optimized.
- No games are installed.
- No temp/ junk files
- Internet Speed is fine.
- Internet Security is updated and working fine.
- In Task Manager, CPU usages and temperature are normal.

However, its performance is low.

- Please guide me for additional steps or in-depth steps for its improved performance.
- And I would like to diagnose its benchmark performance. What applications I can use for it?

With Regards

InTech

Comment: What program suite are you using for anti-virus/malware detection?  Some of the more popular AV products are themselves resource hogs.  I would recommend benchmarking both with AV on and with AV off - you can disconnect from the network to do this if you install the benchmark on the system rather than running from an online app.

Answer (score 2):

The most logical step is to get an SSD for the OS and applications. It seems that you've done what you can from software standpoint. The HDD is the biggest bottleneck of the system at first look. Even if the WD Black is among the best consumer HDDs out there, it can't match the I/O performance of even the cheapest SSD.

Of course you can keep the HDD for storage of larger files (photos, movies, music). You can either do a clean install on the SSD when you get one or you can clone the system partition from the HDD. The former is preferred and won't be such a hassle, especially if you don't have a lot of apps (as you say).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. please let me know what applications I can use for diagnosis of benchmark performance?